# Why doesn't Harry's touch destroy other Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Couldn't Harry Destroy the Horcruxes With His Bare Hands?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/why-couldnt-harry-destroy-the-horcruxes-with-his-bare-hands)

In PS, Harry's touch damages and nearly destroys Quirrell because he is a Horcrux of Voldemort.

Why doesn't Harry's touch have the same effect on other Horcruxes? (Diary, locket, cup, Nagini)?

I'd strongly prefer canonical answers.

Please note that the obvious answers don't seem work:

- Inanimate vs animate (Nagini is animate)
- Made before Harry's protection by Lily was in place (Nagini was made after)
- Made after Voldemort got new body with Harry's blood (doesn't make sense anyway, bu Nagini works as counter-example)

**NOTE**: Please note that Harry explicitly **did** touch Nagini (in DH), therefore the accepted answer by Kevin to Slytherincess' question that this is a duplicate of seems wrong since Kevin's answer seems to explicitly ignore Nagini.

[Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22507/could-quirinus-quirrell-have-killed-harry-using-avada-kedavra-while-hosting-vold)

Comment: @Slytherincess - well I feel less like a complete idiot because at least I was not the one who answered that one :) VTC

Comment: @Slytherincess - Having said that, the answer to your question completely does NOT satisfy me since I explicitly zeroed in on Nagini as a living Horcrux which contradicts Kevin's answer's main point as he himself pointed out. I'm VTCing anyway, but I need a better answer than "Well, Nagini is an exception"

Comment: DVK, a possible explanation for why Nagini was not hurt when Harry touched her was that he touched her *after* Voldemort had protected himself with Harry's blood.

Comment: @NominSim - Possible but IMHO unlikely. Nagini contained a piece of his soul split off BEFORE that protection happened.

Comment: I agree that it seems unlikely, though it seems like the only *reasonable* canon explanation for the discrepancy.

Comment: I see what you're saying about Nagini and it's an apt point. My question asked why couldn't Harry destroy the Horcruxes with his mere touch. He clearly wasn't able destroy the locket, cup, diadem, or ring with his touch. But his touch did seem to react differently to humans or living creatures -- look what happened to Quirrell at Harry's mere touch. Of course, Quirrell was only a quasi-Horcrux, while Nagini was a full blown one. I would imagine a bona fide Horcrux has exceptional magical powers protecting it; I'll bet Quirrell did not have these protections because Quirrell was expendable. :)